# How to assign one program (Synergy) to use one (of 2) network connections?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, synergy, connection-sharing

I use synergy at work to share my keyboard/house with a laptop. There is hardwire and wireless connections at work, with hardwired on 10.1.X.X and wireless 192.168.X.X. I really need to only have synergy use the hard-wired connection just for the responsiveness of the mouse. Everything else can use wireless.

Is this possible? I've heard of ForceBindIP but was wondering if there's something simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address that the client connects to determines the route through the network it takes to the client.

If your client connects to your 10.1.X.X IP address it will be using the wired network.

If it connects to your 192.168.X.X IP address it will be using the wireless.

There is no need to 'bind' the application to a specific IP address or interface.

Comment: Although ideally synergy would support a bind type feature. Many server-type applications do such as OpenSSH.

Comment: Usually as a security measure to deny access from networks you don't want access from (like only internal networks and not the internet in the case of software running on a gateway machine) - not something that's ever likely to be a requirement for something like synergy